# Java use only whole numbers

Tags: java

I am writing a program to find all combinations of addition, subtractions, division, and multiplication of a string of numbers ... Problem is Java is outputting numbers that are "close" to the target. I.e. if the target is 20 ... when I have `if(number == target){...}` - numbers such as 23, 18, etc are accepted ...

Also can you do a check with the Math library for whole numbers ?

Code for checking if equals target:

```
if(total1 == target){
       System.out.println(a + " = " + total1);  
}
```

Comment: can you show more code? Take a look at Math.round(float arg0) : int

Comment: I don't think I understand your question.. I might be answered something else.. Please elaborate more on this.

Comment: If `target = 20`, the `if-condition` is true for number `23, 18`? How is this possible?

Comment: *"if the target is 20 ... when I have if(number == target){...} - numbers such as 23, 18, etc are accepted"* ... no, they're not. Please post code that demonstrates the issue you are having.

Comment: You need to atleast tell the datatypes of total1 and target for anyone to answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using BigDecimal instead of primitves and Objects like double and Float.

E.g.

```
int total1 = new BigDecimal (5).divide (new BigDecimal(2).intValue ();
```